# Q: How long should Bolognese sauce be stored in the fridge?

Tags: sauce, storage-lifetime, pasta, ground-beef

We made a big batch of Bolognese sauce (ground beef, tomatoes, veggies) and are wondering if we should store part of it in the freezer and eat the other part over the next week.

What is the optimal time to store cooked Bolognese in the fridge?

Comment: @moscafj: I would’ve recommended https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/12010/67. …. But there’s the ‘optimal’ aspect of the question, as many dishes are better the next day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might see some improvement with the flavors melding if it spends a day in the fridge.

But after more than a couple of days, you start to get into the questionable food safety / food poisoning risk territory.

You also risk getting burned out on it, and wanting some more variety in your diet if you have it day after day.

If it were me, I’d try to keep at most 2-3 days worth in the fridge, and freeze the rest.  If it gets to day three, and you haven’t finished it off by then, I would use it in a lasagne or some other casserole, rather than trying to add what’s in the freezer.