# Freezing cooked rice?

Tags: freezing, rice

I accidentally made way too much rice for a dinner party. My wife and I definitely can't eat it all over the next few days, and after that it will probably go bad. Is it possible to freeze rice that has already been cooked? It's flavored so unfortunately we can't use it for fried rice.

Comment: Freezing cooked rice would be a good way to break up the fibres to achieve rice suitable for rice custard quicker. Like I would freeze carrots so that I don't have to microwave them too long to have soft carrots in my ramen soup.

Comment: @blessed It doesn't work this way. There are no cell walls inside of a rice kernel, unlike the cell walls in carrots. Freezing softens cellulose, but not starch.

Comment: "There are no cell walls inside of a rice kernel". Really?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. See my answer here: [Safe to wash rice the night before and leave overnight before cooking?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/41142/safe-to-wash-rice-the-night-before-and-leave-overnight-before-cooking/41146#41146) Just don't put it in the refrigerator first, portion it in the amount you will use at one time, put it into ziplocks and freeze. Of course, for food safety reasons you have to move quickly.

Comment: yep, I do this all the time. I usually freeze it in ice cube trays so that I can pick up as many cubes as I need, otherwise a big chunk is harder to defrost in one go.